# Gradient mesh to blur photos

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, blur

I'm trying to apply a gradient mesh to a photo in illustrator to create a blurred vector background. It limits me to using 50 x 50 columns and the results are very blocky. I had downloaded a vector from iStock for work purposes and noticed that the blurred background had much more than a 50 x 50 grid and it was very smooth lake a gaussian blur effect. I can't find anything about how to achieve this. I'm using CS4 if that makes a difference.

Here is the image I want to emulate:
[image]

Here is my attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator is not the only app that does gradient meshes. The original image could have been generated in another app.

However, I suspect something like this is most often created by using the [**Mesh Tormentor plug in**](http://meshtormentor.com/) for Illustrator. Or rather, if I were creating something similar that's certainly what I'd use.

[image]

- Embed Raster image
- Create mesh object
- increase mesh density (**Mesh Tormentor**)
- select mesh and embedded raster image
- pick up colors from underlying raster for mesh points (**Mesh Tormentor**)
- delete raster

This is a CS6 animated GIF, but Mesh Tormentor is available for all AI versions from CS4 onward (with improvements in newer versions).

The built in `Convert to Gradient Mesh` menu item in Illustrator is really only sufficient for small bits of artwork, not really full photos.